# sort , filter and search with nuxt 2.12 fetch method

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new in Nuxt.js and I use async fetch to get data from my api but i have no idea how to implement Sort,Filter and search in nuxt.this is my code:

```
async fetch() {
    const posts = await fetch(`http://example.com/api/posts`).then((res) => res.json());
    this.posts = this.posts.concat(posts);
}
```

and i pass the 'posts' data to my component with a for loop to show all.
Now i need some buttons to replace fetched content with user desired sort or filter type or searched keyword but i have no idea how to do it.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To Sort, filter ,search & Paginate API result you can use something like this:

```
<template>
 <div class="page-wrapper">
   <div class="article-cards-wrapper">
    <article-card-block
      v-for="(article, i) in articles"
      :key="article.id"
      :article="article"
      class="article-card-block"/>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

 <script>
 import ArticleCardBlock from '@/components/blocks/ArticleCardBlock'

 export default {
   components: {
      ArticleCardBlock
  },
  data() {
return {
    currentPage: 1,
  articles: []
  }
},
async fetch() {
const articles = await fetch(`https://example.com/api/articles?tag=nuxt&state=rising&page=${this.currentPage}`).then((res) => res.json())

 this.articles = this.articles.concat(articles)
 }
}
</script>
```

Here You can read the [Full Article](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/build-dev-to-clone-with-nuxt-new-fetch#using-code-fetch-code-in-page-components)
You can also use this new brand nuxt.js fetch method with it's useful cache solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed property or method to return a filtered/sorted copy of this.posts.  You would pass *that* to the for loop in your component, instead of the raw data in this.posts.

Comment: should i fetch data again from the api every time and refresh this.posts? I think it is necessary in search. would you please send me any example?